# mongoose models to breezejs metadata

Tags: mongoose, breeze, single-page-application

I'm using mongoose on the back-end to define my models; so on the front-end I would like to let breezeJS know about the metadata.

Is there any way to create metadata out the schemas defined with mongoose?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to write a small npm package that deals with this issue

https://www.npmjs.org/package/breeze-mongoose

```
//Create a function that returns a mongoose model

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),

   dbConnection = mongoose.createConnection(mongodb_connection_string),

   modelContainer = function getModel(model){ // the name of the model
     return dbConnection .model(model);
   },

   dbSchemas = dbConnection.models;

//Add the getMetadata endpoint to your API

    var breezeMongoose = require('breeze-mongoose')(modelContainer);

    app.get('breeze/metadata', function(req, res){
         res.json(breezeMongoose.getMetadata(dbSchemas ));
    })

//Add the saveChanges endpoint

app.post(function(req, res){
        breezeMongoose.saveChanges(req.body)
            .then(function(saveResults){
             res.json(saveResults);
        })
        .catch(function(message){
            res.send(500, message);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, but it is a good idea.  Maybe you could add this as a request on the breeze User Voice . You can vote for it here: https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-1-breezejs-feature-suggestions